# Syntax for ng-repeat angular directive and pipe character

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am studying the angularJS home page samples and I came across the following usage of the angularJS ng-repeat directive:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
```

**Is the pipe character an angularJS keyword or a plain JS keyword?** Also, what is the desired effect of this keyword?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pipe character has special meaning in AngularJS [expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) language and is used to invoke [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

In short: **this is AngularJS keyword** to invoke filters.

Answer (score 3):

It's an Angular keyword/symbol which is used when you want to apply some Angular filter to the input.
In this case you may read the expression as follows:

1. Take `projects` collection,
2. Apply `search` filter on it,
3. Than take the result of the `search` filter and apply the `orderBy` filter on it,
4. Than take the result of the `orderBy` filter and feed it to ng-repeat